# MVVMCross: CreatePresenter() is never called in MvvmCrossTouch setup

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I would like to define a custom presenter to customise my UI a little, to implement a split view on iPad and so on. I defined this class:

```
class ProjectPresenter : MvxTouchViewPresenter
{
    public ProjectPresenter(UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window) : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        IMvxTouchView viewController = this.CreateViewControllerFor(request);
        this.Show(viewController);
    }
}
```

And I registered it in my MvxTouchSetup class like so:

```
protected override IMvxTouchViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
{
    MvxTrace.Trace("Creating the presenter!");
    return new ProjectPresenter(this.ApplicationDelegate, this.Window);
}
```

However, breakpoints in the Show() method are never hit. I tried adding breakpoints to all overloads of Show(), ChangePresentation(), etc, but they are never hit. Now, I know that Xamarin.iOS is fairly unreliable where breakpoints are concerned but even putting in trace methods yields no joy. I even replaced the CreatePresenter() method with a method that throws an exception and the app didn't crash.

Other modifications to my application show up when I deploy them, so this isn't some sort of caching problem, although I have cleaned both the sources on my PC and on my Mac as well. Furthermore, the breakpoint in the constructor of my setup class is being hit, so this is perhaps not even a Xamarin-related problem at all.

I'm guessing that I'm either relying on older documentation or I'm doing something very very silly (I'm guessing the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think that `CreatePresenter` wouldn't be called is if you are using the older 'presenter-based' constructor for your `Setup`

---

`MvxTouchSetup` provides two different constructors:

```
    protected MvxTouchSetup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
    {
        _window = window;
        _applicationDelegate = applicationDelegate;
    }

    protected MvxTouchSetup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, IMvxTouchViewPresenter presenter)
    {
        _presenter = presenter;
        _applicationDelegate = applicationDelegate;
    }
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Platform/MvxTouchSetup.cs#L39

By default in Nuget-based projects and in most of the MvvmCross samples, the first of these is used.

However, the second form actually existed first and so it's still around for historical reasons - to prevent older apps from breaking. If you use it, then the `CreatePresenter()` is not used - it's not needed because you've supplied a presenter during construction.

Comment: And now when I read the contents of my AppDelegate, it all seems so obvious. Thanks Stuart!

Comment: Might it be a good idea to add an ```[Obsolete]``` tag to that older constructor?